# Error in Converting LLaMA 13B weights to HuggingFace format

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

I have downloaded the LLaMA weights for the 7B and 13B model, and was able to successfully convert the 7B model weights to torch binary files based on the script provided by HuggingFace [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/llama/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py), however when converting the 13B model, I received the following error.

```
Fetching all parameters from the checkpoint at /content/drive/MyDrive/User/NLP/Base_Models/Llama_weights/13B.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/User/NLP/Base_Models/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py", line 278, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/User/NLP/Base_Models/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py", line 268, in main
    write_model(
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/User/NLP/Base_Models/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py", line 151, in write_model
    [
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/User/NLP/Base_Models/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py", line 152, in <listcomp>
    loaded[i][f"layers.{layer_i}.attention.wq.weight"].view(n_heads_per_shard, dims_per_head, dim)
RuntimeError: shape '[20, 128, 5120]' is invalid for input of size 16777216
```

Any advice on what to do with this situation? The reason I want these weights is also to get the StableVicuna model which builds on it.

Note: In case the following details are relevant, due to the limited RAM and VRAM on my machine, I am using Google Colab to convert the weights, and I installed the following libraries:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/zphang/transformers.git@llama_push torch
```